# Perl GD Library - Flickering PNG Output

Tags: perl, png, gd, libpng

When i was trying to get a PNG output from Perl's GD component (version 2.46, http://metacpan.org/pod/GD), the resulting image flickers when opened with ImageMagick. Same kind of behaviour can also obtained via exporting in GIF, **but not in JPEG**.

An example code that I used is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                                 

use GD;
$width = 750;
$height = 600;
$im = new GD::Image($width,$height);

$white = $im->colorAllocate(255,255,255);
$black = $im->colorAllocate(0,0,0);
@colors = ();
open(RGB,"heatmap.lut") || die "Cannot open LUT file!";
@colorLines = <RGB>;
close RGB;
foreach my $color (@colorLines){
    $color =~ s/[\r\n]//g;
    push @colors, $im->colorAllocate(split(/\t/,$color));
}
$im->transparent($white);
$im->interlaced('false');
$counterY = 0;
for (my $y=0;$y<600;$y+=30){
    $counterX=0;
    for (my $x=0;$x<750;$x+=30){
        $randnum = int(rand(26));
        $im->filledRectangle($x+1,$y+1,$x+29,$y+29,$colors[$randnum]);
        $counterX++;
    }
    $counterY++;
}

open(TOPNG,">test.png") || die;
binmode TOPNG;
print TOPNG $im->png;
close TOPNG;
```

A video showing this flickering behaviour can be seen in following link: http://youtu.be/EErvl8E7ijc.
It does not clearly show in video but sometimes, the image I wanted to originally draw is seen between those flickers.

When I further investigate the png via "**identify**" command, I get that it is in PsuedoClass instead of regular DirectClass output i get from a regular png.

Any ideas why this is happening or how it can be solved?

Thanks a lot!

A bit of more information:

Remote Server that i work on: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)

The host system i use to connect: Mac OSX Mountain Lion with XQuartz 2.7.2

libpng Version: 1.5.11

ImageMagick Version: 6.5.4-7 2012-04-10 Q16

**EDIT:** `heatmap.lut` file can be found here: http://pastebin.com/vgw5MnTD

Comment: Cannot reproduce, `heatmap.lut` is missing. - I suspect the bug's in ImageMagick's display command, or the X stack below. Does the image look fine in other image viewers/web browsers?

Comment: heatmap.lut can be found here: http://pastebin.com/vgw5MnTD . It seems that it's working in Mac OSX's Preview 6.0 properly. However, since i'll start a massive amount of image generation, i just wanted to be sure that nothing wrong with the pngs.

Comment: You mention your ImageMagick version, but ImageMagick is not a dependency of GD.

Comment: I added that to address the possibility that it may be a bug in ImageMagick's display command as daxim implied, instead it is being something related to GD.